# SoundCloud Group Playlist Player Iframe

Tags: soundcloud

any suggestions on an iframe for a soundcloud player that shows a playlist from a soundcloud group to go in a wordpress page - i.e., http://soundcloud.com/groups/buddhatunes

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin – http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/soundcloud-shortcode/

Install it, and then placing the following in the content body

```
[soundcloud]http://soundcloud.com/groups/buddhatunes[/soundcloud]
```

should work.